# Scrapy items change column name

Tags: python, scrapy, scrapy-item

Is there a way to change column name in csv output, for example, i have scrapy item like this:

```
import scrapy

class Myitems(scrapy.Item):
    recordi = scrapy.Field()
```

and in my spider script I use:

```
item['recordi'] = ....
```

and I use scrapy command

```
scrapy crawl myspider -o data.csv
```

and name of the column in data.csv is also recordi, so my question is, can I change column name, is there any argument for scapy.Field(), where I can define column name, it it stays recordi field name, but column name should be Recor Di

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

AFIAK there is no such mechanism built-in scrapy, when you define field name in item, and you have different name for exporting it. I think you may do it programmatically by creating your customized CSV exporter. When you use this custom experter it can look for field names. You can achieve similar results using some kind of postprocessing script.

Comment: OK, thank you. I taught that there is some function for this

Answer (score -1):

Assuming that the problem you have is that the `field` names have to adhere to python variable names syntax, you can simply define the `field` as below instead i.e. below format allows field names to contain characters such as spaces which are not valid python variable names.

```
import scrapy

class Myitems(scrapy.Item):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.fields["Recor Di"] = scrapy.Field()
```

in your spider you can then populate the item as below

```
item['Recor Di'] = ....
```

your csv column name will then be `Recor Di` as well.